# In Calendar how to all date are highlight in codeginter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Store all database data in  array like this

```
                foreach($da as $abc) {
                    $myarray[] = array(                              
                      date("j", strtotime($abc ->date)) => ''
                    );
                  }
```

$myarray contain all date which is fetch into database

then this all date pass into codeigniter calender like this

```
 for ($i=0; $i <count($myarray) ; $i++) {                        
        $abc= $this->calendar->generate(2018, 12, $myarray[$i]);
    }
$this->load->view('calen',['va'=>$abc]);
```

And in my View simple print `echo $va`

but problem is only last index date are show or highlight in calender so how to highlight all date in the calendar

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change this loop :

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($myarray) ; $i++) {                        
    $abc= $this->calendar->generate(2018, 12, $myarray[$i]);
}
```

With this :

```
$passed_date = array();
foreach ($myarray as $value) {
    $passed_date += $value;
}
$abc = $this->calendar->generate(2018, 12, $passed_date);
```